# Given a web page as a string, how extract the data of a particular table knowing its id?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, web-scraping

I have a webpage HTML as a string. There is a table present in the webpage. I know its id. I want extract the data from the table. What is the best way of doing that in C#?

For example(Bad indent)

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="TABLE_ID" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <th scope="col"> A </th><th scope="col"> B </th><th scope="col"> C </th><th scope="col"> D </th>
    <th scope="col"> E </th><th scope="col"> F </th><th scope="col"> G </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>123456abc</td><td>john smith</td><td>01/12/2017</td><td>00/00/0000</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>RTA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>123456abc</td><td>john smith</td><td>01/12/2007</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>RTA</td>
</tr>
```

I can always do it by writing the code for parsing the string as desired but there sure must be better ways for doing this.

Comment: Look at [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) if you're comfortable or willing to try Python.

Comment: You may want to review the [wikipedia document on web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Comment: I have settled on [HTMLAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).Works fine.